# C# Console - Drawing Black & White pixels

Tags: c#, .net

<sup>I have already asked the same question before</sup>

I want and need a way to draw pixels in C# Console Application, but not the way most people would think it is.

1. Draw `x` by `y` white pixels.
2. Whenever I ask it to, save pixel located at `x`,`y`. I can add as more pixels as I want.
3. Display white board, but all pixels saved in memory will be displayed as black. And clear every pixel in memory afterall.

---

I've tried to implement the same code that I want/need over **4** times already. Here's the most stable code. Please try this library (program) if you don't understand what I need, I'd personally like to call it **PxDrawEasy** - for drawing pixels in a Console Application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using static PxDrawEasy;

public class PxDrawEasy
{
    // NewPixel(x, y) - Add pixel at X and Y.
    // InitializeGrid(x, y) - Set grid size to be X and Y.
    // Clear() - Clear all pixels in memory, grid, grid initialization, grid size, and so on.
    // RemovePixels() - Clear all pixels saved in memory.
    // ClearDisplay() - Clear the display.
    // RefreshDisplay() - Refreshes the grid, and shows all pixels in the memory.
    // DrawRectangle(x, y) - Draws a rectangle X wide and Y long.
    
    static List<int> XValues = new List<int>();
    static List<int> YValues = new List<int>();
    static int VerticalGridSize = 0; // Y
    static int HorizontalGridSize = 0; // X
    static bool GridInitialized = false;
    
    public static void InitializeGrid(int x, int y)
    {
        if (GridInitialized)
        {
            Console.ResetColor(); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.WriteLine("PxDrawEasy error: Grid already initialized."); Console.ResetColor(); return;
        } else GridInitialized = true;
        
        VerticalGridSize = y;
        HorizontalGridSize = x;
        DrawRectangle(x, y);
    }
    
    public static void DrawRectangle(int x, int y)
    {
        Console.ResetColor();
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < x; b++)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White; Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("Ty");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    
    public static void NewPixel(int x, int y)
    {
        if (VerticalGridSize == 0 || HorizontalGridSize == 0 || !GridInitialized)
        {
            Console.ResetColor(); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.WriteLine("PxDrawEasy error: Grid is not yet initialized."); Console.ResetColor(); return;
        }
        
        if (VerticalGridSize < x || HorizontalGridSize < y)
        {
            Console.ResetColor(); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.WriteLine($"PxDrawEasy error: Pixel {x}x{y} is outside of the bounds of a generated grid (grid size: {HorizontalGridSize}x{VerticalGridSize})."); Console.ResetColor(); return;
        }
        
        XValues.Add(x);
        YValues.Add(y);
    }
    
    public static void Clear()
    {
        XValues.Clear();
        YValues.Clear();
        GridInitialized = false;
        HorizontalGridSize = 0;
        VerticalGridSize = 0;
        Console.ResetColor(); Console.Clear();
    }
    
    public static void ClearDisplay()
    {
        Console.ResetColor(); Console.Clear();
    }
    
    public static void RemovePixels()
    {
        XValues.Clear();
        YValues.Clear();
    }
    
    public static void RefreshDisplay()
    {
        Console.ResetColor(); Console.Clear();
        
        for (int y = 1; y < VerticalGridSize +1; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 1; x < HorizontalGridSize +1; x++)
            {
                bool DRAWNOW = false;
                foreach (var item in YValues.ToList())
                {
                    foreach (var Item in XValues.ToList())
                    {
                        if (y == Convert.ToInt32(item) && x == Convert.ToInt32(Item))
                        {
                            XValues.Remove(x);
                            YValues.Remove(y);
                            DRAWNOW = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                if (DRAWNOW)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    Console.Write("ll");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                } else {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.Write("ll");
                    Console.ResetColor();
                }
                DRAWNOW = false;
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        InitializeGrid(8, 8);
        NewPixel(1, 1);
        NewPixel(1, 8);
        NewPixel(8, 1);
        NewPixel(8, 8);
        RefreshDisplay();
    }
}
```

It works as intended, except that I cannot draw multiple pixels in one same line.

**I can also appreciate it if someone lets me know if I can use any library that does the same (if there is one), but it must have open source code. *No, I am not asking for downloading libraries (because I don't think that's allowed on StackOverflow), but if that's the only possible choice, then sure.***

---

Can anyone help? I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your 'Pixel' means a character with a specific color.

Well, I'm not sure what your code actually does, but it is most likely not a good way to do it. I would instead recommend that you keep a buffer of your intended colors, so you can draw complete lines:

```
var frameBuffer = new ConsoleColor[10, 10]; // defaults to black

frameBuffer[1, 6] = ConsoleColor.White;
frameBuffer[6, 1] = ConsoleColor.White;

for (int x = 0; x < frameBuffer.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < frameBuffer.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = frameBuffer[x, y];
        Console.Write('_');
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

But note that this is a *terrible* way to draw anything. I know ASCII art is a thing, and some even get good enough performance to play games using an ascii renderer. But I'm not sure that is even possible in the windows console, and if it is, you likely need to use something more advanced than this. I would advice using the actual graphics APIs if you actually want to do anything graphics related.